# how to get the value from ajax url to action class and redirect on the same page as popup in java

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am new to ajax, I have tried with below example to to take the bookid from checkbox and pass it to javascript. If user is already ordered that bookid then popup a message that You have already order this bookid. I am trying to do this with ajax, javascript. But my program is not running.Please help me.

Booking.jsp Page: which has a table of all the books available

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlHttp;

function sendRequest(bookid)
{
var url = "ajaxcall.action?bookID="+bookid;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest()
}
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)
      {
      xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } 

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = getResponse;
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function getResponse()
{
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
    {
    if(xmlHttp.status == 200)
        {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="booking" method="post"> 

    <table border="2" align="center" >
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th > bookID   </th>
            <th > bookName      </th>
            <th > Description    </th>
            <th > AuthorName      </th>

            <th > bookStatus    </th>

        </tr>
        <s:iterator value="bookList">
            <tr>
                <td><s:checkbox name="bookListID" fieldValue="%{bookID}" theme="simple" onclick= "sendRequest(this.value)"/></td>
                        <td><s:property value="%{bookID}" /></td>
                <td><s:property value="%{bookName}" /></td>
                <td><s:property value="%{description}" /></td>
                <td><s:property value="%{authorName}" /></td>
                <td><s:property value="%{bookStatus}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>

    </table>
    </br>
    <s:submit id="submitbook" value="booking" theme="simple"></s:submit>

    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Strut.xml file:

```
<action name="ajaxcall" class="com.wipro.tns.action.BookingAction" method="ajaxcall">
        <result name="success">/Booking.jsp</result>
        <result name="failure">/Failure.jsp</result>        
    </action>
```

BookingAction.java

```
  public String ajaxcall() {
            System.out.println("in ajax call");
            User user = new User();
            String result = user.bookStatus(bookid);
            // this bookid is the value of checkbox bookid and bookStatus() use to check the status like already booked or not
            if(result.equals("alreadybooked")
            {
              //then it show popup in Booking.jsp page that you have already order this book
            }
            else
            {
               // user can book the bookid
             }
            return "failure" 
        }
```

Comment: I'd advise against trying to roll your own version of AJAX in the browser. jQuery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and similar frameworks will give you a much better wrapper handling all bugs/deficiencies in browsers.

Comment: You should add more console messages, for better debugging ;)

Comment: use `bookID` instead of `bookid`.and need little more explanation.`String result = user.bookStatus(bookID);   //use bookID `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.first include you javascript file.`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` inside header  tag.

2.put your function inside after docuemtn ready  `$(document).ready(function(){ var xmlHttp;........your code...... });`

3.while calling ajax funciton.use `bookID` instead of `bookid`.and need little more explanation.`String result = user.bookStatus(bookID);   //use bookID`